# Get Duplicates from Object in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js, lodash

I need some help with `getting duplicate Object from the Object`, I keep getting stuck.

**For Example**

```
My Object = {1: 'cat', 2: 'dog', 3: 'cat'}
```

**Expected Result should be**

```
{1: 'cat'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could count the occurences with a map and get the first found key/value pair for the result set.

```js
var object = { 1: 'cat', 2: 'dog', 3: 'cat' },
    result = Object.assign(
        ...Array.from(
            Object
                .entries(object)
                .reduce((m, [k, v]) => (([l, c]) => m.set(v, [l, c + 1]))(m.get(v) || [k, -1]), new Map),
            ([v, [k, c]]) => c && { [k]: v }
        )
    );

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using lodash, you can convert the object to an array of pairs, group them by the value, and remove groups without duplicates, and convert back to an array:

```js
const object = { 1: 'cat', 2: 'dog', 3: 'cat' }

const fn = _.flow([
  _.toPairs, // convert to pairs [key, value]
  o => _.groupBy(o, _.last), // group the pairs by the value
  o => _.filter(o, g => g.length > 1), // filter out group with no duplicates
  o => _.map(o, _.first), // get the 1st item from each group
  _.fromPairs // convert back to object
])

const result = fn(object)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another implementation based on [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
const o = { 1: 'cat', 2: 'dog', 3: 'cat' }

const result = Object.entries(o).reduce((r, [k,v], idx, arr) => {
  r[v] = [...(r[v] || []), { [k]: v }]
  return idx == arr.length-1 ? Object.values(r).find(x => x.length > 1)[0] : r
}, {})
console.log(result)
```

Here it is broken down with more details:

```js
const object = { 1: 'cat', 2: 'dog', 3: 'cat' }

const result = 
  Object.entries(object)  // get object key & value in the form of [key,value]
  .reduce((accumulator, [k,v], index, array) => {  // start an `Array.reduce`
  // create the grouping on the value `cat`/`dog`
  accumulator[v] = [...(accumulator[v] || []), { [k]: v }] 
  if(index == array.length-1)  // if we are at the end of the `Array.reduce`
    // Return the values of the accumulator filtered by the arrays which length is more than 1
    // and take from that array the initial element 
    return Object.values(accumulator).find(x => x.length > 1)[0]
  else // Not at the end keep returning the accumulator
    return accumulator
}, {})

console.log(result)
```